# How to deal with "Error: Multiple solutions found"?

Tags: idris, idris2

I'm trying to build a set datatype.

```
mutual

  data Set : Type -> Type where
    Nil : Eq a => Set a
    (::) : Eq a => (x : a) -> (s : Set a) -> {auto _ : contains x s = False} -> Set a

  contains : Eq a => a -> Set a -> Bool
  contains x [] = False
  contains x (y :: s) = (x == y) || contains x s
```

But I have no idea how to deal with this error:

```
Error: While processing right hand side of contains. Multiple solutions found in search of:
    Eq a

test:9:26--9:32
 5 |     (::) : Eq a => (x : a) -> (s : Set a) -> {auto _ : contains x s = False} -> Set a
 6 |
 7 |   contains : Eq a => a -> Set a -> Bool
 8 |   contains x [] = False
 9 |   contains x (y :: s) = (x == y) || contains x s
                              ^^^^^^

Possible correct results:
    conArg (implicitly bound at test:9:3--9:49)
    conArg (implicitly bound at test:9:3--9:49)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple instances of `Eq a` floating around (one for each set element), so Idris isn't sure which one to use. For example, in `contains`, there's one from `contains : Eq a =>` and another less obvious one from `(y :: s)`. You can disambiguate with

```
  contains : Eq a => a -> Set a -> Bool
  contains x [] = False
  contains @{eq} x (y :: s) = ((==) @{eq} x y) || contains @{eq} x s
```

though it may be better to work out some refactor that doesn't have multiple `Eq a`, if that's possible.

Comment: Looks like I can just remove constrain from contains: `contains : a -> Set a -> Bool` and all typechecks. Thank you, I would never guess that another constrain had come from `(y :: s)`.